# Decode JPG byte array to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I have a raspberry Pi 4 equipped with Camera, and a process is capturing image using OpenCV library. This image is then forwarded to two destinations:

1. Standard laptop equipped with Arch Linux
2. Android smartphone

This is the Image server on the Raspberry PI (C++):

```
#define MAX_IMAGESIZE 40090
typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    uint16_t len;
    uint8_t data[MAX_IMAGESIZE];
} image_msg;

void __attribute__((noreturn)) camera_task()
{
    cv::VideoCapture capture(0);
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    struct sockaddr_in pcaddr, phaddr;

    memset(&pcaddr, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    memset(&phaddr, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    pcaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    pcaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(PC_ADDRESS);
    pcaddr.sin_port = htons(4321);

    phaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    phaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(PH_ADDRESS);
    phaddr.sin_port = htons(4321);

    if (!capture.isOpened())
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cv::Mat frame;
    while (1)
    {
        if (!capture.read(frame))
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        cv::flip(frame, frame, -1);
        std::vector<int> params;
        std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;

        params.push_back(cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
        params.push_back(60);
        cv::imencode(".jpg", frame, buffer, params);
    
        image_msg outmsg;
        outmsg.len = static_cast<uint16_t>(buffer.size());
        for(uint16_t i = 0; i < outmsg.len; i++)
        {
            outmsg.data[i] = buffer[i];
        }
        if(sendto(sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&outmsg), sizeof(outmsg), 0, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&pcaddr), sizeof(pcaddr)) > 0)
        {
             //printf("OK sendto PC\n");
        }
        else
        {
             perror("Camera task to PC");
        }
        if(sendto(sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&outmsg), sizeof(outmsg), 0, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&phaddr), sizeof(phaddr)) > 0)
        {
            //printf("OK sendto PHONE\n");
        }
        else
        {
             perror("Camera task to PHONE");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Image client on the laptop (C++):

```
cv::Mat *imagewindow;
void init_window()
{
    init_localsock(&imu_socket, &imu_saddr, IMUPORT); //not related with camera
    init_localsock(&speed_socket, &speed_saddr, VELPORT); //not related with camera
    init_localsock(&attitude_socket, &attitude_saddr, ATTPORT); //not related with camera
    init_localsock(&radiation_socket, &radiation_saddr, RADPORT); //not related with camera
    init_localsock(&throttle_socket, &throttle_saddr, THRPORT); //not related with camera
    init_localsock(&image_socket, &image_saddr, RENPORT); //initialize socket on port 4321

    imagewindow = new cv::Mat(600, 600, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));

    cv::imshow(PROJNAME, *imagewindow);
}
void main_loop(const char* board_address)
{
    while(true)
    {
        imu_task();
        speed_task();
        attitude_task();

        radiation_task();

        throttle_task();

        image_task(); //this is the image receiver task

        render_window();

        cmd_out_task(board_address);
    }
}

void image_task()
{
    image_msg recv; //the same struct defined on the raspberry
    socklen_t len;
    ssize_t bytes_recv = recvfrom(image_socket, &recv, sizeof(image_msg), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&image_saddr, &len);
    if(bytes_recv > 0)
    {
        memset(imagewindow->data, 0x00, imagewindow->dataend - imagewindow->data);
        update_image(recv);
    }
}

void update_image(image_msg image)
{
    std::vector<char> data(image.data, image.data + image.len);
    *imagewindow = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(data), 1);
}
```

And it works fine. Here a screenshot of what's happening:
[image: Image is correctly received from the laptop]

Here we go to the problem. The receiver on android is the following:

```
private byte[] recv_image(DatagramSocket sock) throws Exception
{
    byte[] b = new byte[40090];
    DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length);
    
    byte[] recv_length = new byte[4];
    length[3] = b[0];
    length[2] = b[1];
    int recv_len = ByteBuffer.wrap(length).getInt();
    byte[] image_bytes = new byte[recv_len];
    for(int i = 0; i < recv_len; i++)
    {
        image_bytes[i] = b[4 + i];
    }
    return image_bytes;
}
```

The receive thread is doing:

```
initialize_videosocket(); //init a local UDP socket on port 4321
while(true)
{
     try
     {
         final byte[] imagebytes = recv_image(video_sock);
         Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagebytes, 0, imagebytes.length);
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         Log.d("Exception in image thread: " + e.toString();
     }
 }
```

The problem is that Bitmap bmp is always null. From the documentation, decodeByteArray returns null if the JPG is unvalid. These are the attempts I did:

1. Tried using opencv in my android app:

   ```
    Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(imagebytes), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(rgb, bmp);
   ```

   But `mat.cols()` and `mat.rows()` returns both -1. I forced arguments to be 480,640 (as it should be) and I get an assertion failed on the execution of `Utils.matToBitmap`.
2. Tried to compare received jpg buffers both on the laptop and on the phone. They are equals.
3. Tried to write jpg buffer on a file .jpg and opening it as standard .jpg file with Gimp. It works, so the buffer is containing a correct .jpg file, but the decodeByteArray should return null if the buffer is not a valid .jpg file.

I'm really stuck in this, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `but the decodeByteArray should return null if the buffer is not a valid .jpg file.` You mean:  decodeByteArray should return a bitmap if the buffer contains a valid .jpg file and the resolution of the image is not that big as to the bitmap become to large for available memory. What is its resolution? Try to send a small image as a test.

Comment: `Tried to write jpg buffer on a file .jpg ` You did that with Android code on your Android device?

Comment: As for the first question, the resolution is 640x480 (width, height), here an example: https://ibb.co/RccSkTY

As for the second, i did that with the PC. In android i cannot access the /data folder of the app, this is another funny thing to deal with

Comment: That is very small. Should not be a problem.  byte[] image_bytes = new byte[recv_len]; So recv_len is the size in bytes of the jpg the sever sends ? Did you check that?

Comment: Yes I checked it, recv_len is correct

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Issue, it was trivial.

The android function which receives image was doing:

```
private byte[] recv_image(DatagramSocket sock) throws Exception
{
    byte[] b = new byte[40090];
    DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length);

    byte[] recv_length = new byte[4];
    length[3] = b[0];
    length[2] = b[1];
    int recv_len = ByteBuffer.wrap(length).getInt();
    byte[] image_bytes = new byte[recv_len];
    for(int i = 0; i < recv_len; i++)
    {
        image_bytes[i] = b[4 + i]; //HERE it is the problem
    }
    return image_bytes;
}
```

The `len` field of the struct is an uint16_t. I need to convert it to an int(32) in Java, in order to avoid negative values which may be evaluated inside a Java program if I use `ByteBuffer.wrap(b, 0, 2).getShort()` because the java short type is signed. The C++ struct the server is sending is declared `__attribute__((packed))`:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    uint16_t len;
    uint8_t data[MAX_IMAGESIZE];
} image_msg;
```

Hence the `data` field begins at base+0x02 and not base+0x04:

```
private byte[] recv_image(DatagramSocket sock) throws Exception
{
    byte[] b = new byte[40090];
    DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length);

    byte[] recv_length = new byte[4];
    length[3] = b[0];
    length[2] = b[1];
    int recv_len = ByteBuffer.wrap(length).getInt();
    byte[] image_bytes = new byte[recv_len];
    for(int i = 0; i < recv_len; i++)
    {
        image_bytes[i] = b[2 + i]; //2 + i instead of 4 + i
    }
    return image_bytes;
}
```

This solution fixed my problem, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urxxb.jpg). Thanks for your support.

Comment: Nice video. That all goes that quick. Racing raspi!

Comment: My lipo batteries are out of charge, unfortunately. It could have been more funnier :)